# Local variables referenced from an inner class must be final or effectively final - Java

Tags: java

When attempting to initialize an ArrayList with an index as a value, I encounter the error message **"local variables referenced from an inner class must be final or effectively final at <add(index);>"**

```
int index=0;    
for (int i:nums){
        if (!map.containsKey(i)){
            ArrayList<Integer> al1=new ArrayList<Integer>(){{
                add(index);
            }};
            map.put(i,al1);
        }
        index+=1;
    }
```

I know there are possible walkarounds where I can just simply declare arraylist then add value to it separately, this works totally fine.

```
ArrayList<Integer> al1=new ArrayList<Integer>();
al1.add(index);
map.put(i,al1);
```

But I want to understand whether there's any way to achieve it during initialization itself.
Please help me with this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You shouldn't use "double brace initialization". It is considered an anti-pattern as it adds extra anonymous classes and can result in memory leaks because - if created in a non-static method - they will retain a reference to the enclosing object. See also [What is Double Brace initialization in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958636/what-is-double-brace-initialization-in-java)

Comment: Thanks @MarkRotteveel. I was not aware about this memory leak issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can initialize a temporary variable to the current `index` value and use that.

```java
final int temp = index; // this is effectively final
ArrayList<Integer> al1=new ArrayList<Integer>(){{
    add(temp);
}};
```

However, in this case, it is probably better to use `List.of`, `Arrays.asList`, or `Collections.singletonList`.

```java
List<Integer> al1 = List.of(index);
// or, if an ArrayList is specifically required:
ArrayList<Integer> al1 = new ArrayList<>(List.of(index));
```

Comment: It's probably best to avoid double braces altogether, as it's an un-idiomatic way of writing Java code.

Comment: @markspace I provided a better method in the second half of my answer.